# php: $_SESSION isn't working

Tags: php

I wanna call a value of one variable into my other php file but it isn't working. First it was showing me my old data except for the new one but now its not even getting any value. This is what i did in first file

```
$_SESSION['tsmUserName']=$username;
```

And this is what i did in the second

```
$ids=$_SESSION['tsmUserName'];
```

I even used Var_dump and it just told me that tsmusername is undefined. When i made the program for the first time everything worked fine but then i changed my primary key to username and it all got messed up and the php form started autofilling the input fields with old deleted values and then when i changed the primary key back to id it still started showing old deleted values. After restarting my computing and checking again, it got worse as now i am getting undefined error. Here r my codes for both the php files just in case:

```
<?php
        $firstnameError = $lastnameError = $usernameError = $passwordError = $birthdateError = $mobileError = $emailError = "";
    // Check if data are posted.
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $firstname = $lastname = $username = $password = $birthdate = $mobile = $email = "";
        $errorOccured = false;

        if (isset($_POST['tsmFirstName'])){
            $firstname = trim($_POST['tsmFirstName']);
            if (strlen($firstname) == 0){
                $firstnameError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $firstnameError = "First Name is missing";
        }

        //Checking last name
        if (isset($_POST['tsmLastName'])){
            $lastname = trim($_POST['tsmLastName']);
            if (strlen($lastname) == 0){
                $lastnameError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $lastnameError = "First Name is missing";
        }

        //checking the username
        if (isset($_POST['tsmUserName'])){
            $username = trim($_POST['tsmUserName']);
            $usernameLenght = strlen($username);
            if ($usernameLenght == 0){
                $usernameError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
            elseif ($usernameLenght < 4){
                $usernameError = "Your username should be minimum 4 characters";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $usernameError = "First Name is missing";
        }


        //checking the password
        if (isset($_POST['tsmPassword'])){
            $password = trim($_POST['tsmPassword']);
            if (strlen($password) == 0){
                $passwordError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $passwordError = "First Name is missing";
        }

        //checking the birthdate
        if (isset($_POST['tsmBirthDate'])){
            $birthdate = trim($_POST['tsmBirthDate']);
            if (strlen($birthdate) == 0){
                $birthdateError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $birthdateError = "First Name is missing";
        }

        // checking the mobile
        if (isset($_POST['tsmMobile'])){
            $mobile = trim($_POST['tsmMobile']);
            if (strlen($mobile) == 0){
                $mobileError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $mobileError = "Mobile is missing";
        }

        //checking the email
        if (isset($_POST['tsmEmail'])){
            $email = trim($_POST['tsmEmail']);
            if (strlen($email) == 0){
                $emailError = "Email is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $emailError = "Email is missing";
        }                                                       


        if(!$errorOccured){
            require_once("connection.php");

        $_SESSION['tsmUserName']=$username;
        $names=$_SESSION['tsmFirstName'];
        var_dump($_SESSION);
            $keychain= sha1($username);
            $my_query="INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, birthdate, mobile, email, status, keychain) VALUES (NULL,'$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password','2016-1-1','$mobile','$email','0','$keychain')";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection,$my_query);
            if($result){
                $message_mail = "Dear $firstname, <br> Thank You for registering with us. Click now on the link below to activate your account. <br> $keychain <br><br> Thank You.";
                $subject_mail= "Your account has been created";
                $to_mail = $email;
                $headers[]= 'MIME-Version 1.0';
                $headers[]= 'content-type:text/html; charset=utf8';
                $headers[]= 'From: admin@tassimo.com';
                mail($to_mail,$subject_mail,$message_mail,implode("\r\n",$headers));
                //after email is sent redirect to thank you page.
                header("Location:completed.php?task=done");
                exit();
                echo 'Thank You';
            }
                else{
                    echo "<b> Error unable to post. </b>";
                    mysqli_error($connection);
                }
                mysqli_close($connection);
            }

        }


?>
```

and the second one that is supposed to take the username from the first one is here

```
<?php
session_start();
$EntryError=$ExitError="";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $entrydate = $exitdate = "";
        $errorOccured = false;

        if (isset($_POST['tsmdate'])){
            $entrydate = trim($_POST['tsmdate']);
            if (strlen($entrydate) == 0){
                $EntryError = "date is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $EntryError = "date is missing";
        }

        // checking for last name
        if (isset($_POST['tsmexit'])){
            $exitdate = trim($_POST['tsmexit']);
            if (strlen($exitdate) == 0){
                $ExitError = "First Name is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $ExitError = "last Name is missing";
        }
        $ids=$_SESSION['tsmUserName'];

        var_dump($_SESSION);
        if(!$errorOccured){
            require_once("connection.php");
            $my_query="INSERT INTO timing (`No`, `Entry Date and Time`, `Exit Date and Time`, `Username`) VALUES (NULL,'$EntryError','$exitdate','$ids')";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection,$my_query);
            if($result)
            {
                echo 'thank you';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'error';
            }
            mysqli_close($connection);
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: You have to call `session_start()` in both files

Comment: OMG thats it.. I was loosing my mind over this! Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every web page that needs access to `$_SESSION` must call the `session_start()` function first.

As per Marcin's comment, this can also be accomplished by setting the session to auto start in the php.ini file without using the `session_start()` function on every page.

```
session.auto_start=On
```

Comment: This answer is actually incorrectly phrased. Proper answer should say that `session_start()` needs to be called prior accessing `$_SESSION`, yet you can have this handled with [session.auto_start](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) php.ini's option too, and you will be all good not calling `session_start()` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sinfieldd mentioned previously, you should start the session at the very beginning of every php script in order to access the session array,
to do so add the following code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = "value";

// and clear the session when you're done, for example when the user logs out
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to start a session for it to work. To start a session use `session_start()`